# SELECT statement from multiple tables with distinct rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, inner-join

I am trying to perform a select statement that will grab data from table1 based on the sub_id (primary), but then grab the user's phone numbers from another table also based on the same sub_id. However I would like all of this to be in the same (single) record.

So for example, there is a user record in table 1 that has all the user's info like name, address, etc. However they may have 3 corresponding records in the phone numbers table under their sub_id for their home number (comm_type v for voice), mobile phone (comm_type t for text) and finally their spouse's mobile (comm_type t for text). I would like to run a select query that will get the following:

```
SELECT name, address,
    (select phonenumber as mobile1 from phonenumbers table where table1.sub_id = phone numbers.sub_id and comm_type = 't'),
    (select phonenumber as mobile2 from phonenumbers table where table1.sub_id = phone numbers.sub_id and comm_type = 't'),
    (select phonenumber as mobile3 from phonenumbers table where table1.sub_id = phone numbers.sub_id and comm_type = 't'),
    (select phonenumber as voice1 from phonenumbers table where table1.sub_id = phone numbers.sub_id and comm_type = 'v'),
    (select phonenumber as voice2 from phonenumbers table where table1.sub_id = phone numbers.sub_id and comm_type = 'v'),
FROM table1
```

However I would like to make sure that it is in some kind of loop so it doesn't keep grabbing the first mobile number over and over. I would like the result to be one record like the following:

```
name | address | mobile1 | mobile2 | mobile3 | voice1 | voice2 | voice3
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select from multiple rows without duplicate (inner join) records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243658/select-from-multiple-rows-without-duplicate-inner-join-records)

Comment: This is a copy+paste of your question six days ago - please do not deliberately duplicate posts. It did not have many eyeballs because you did not tag it with the database engine you're using. Please add that - `mysql`?

Comment: Halfer, thank you for the input as I am new to this forum and certainly do not want to "put off" anyone here that would be offering their time and experience at no cost to them. I will go in right now to add the db tags.

Comment: Thank you once again....

Comment: No worries. I'd suggest adding some input data, the structure of your tables. For bonus points, prepare a SQL Fiddle, and add the link at the end of the question - that allows folks to play around with your query very easily. (I've converted the query to a formatted block, so people can more easily see the structure you're using).

Comment: My instinct is that if you have more than one number for any of these fields, you should get an error - that's what happens in MySQL, at any rate. I would add a `LIMIT 1`, or the SQL Server equivalent, to resolve that. I expect there is an equivalent of `OFFSET` so you can retrieve the Nth number (where N > 1).